# How to improve MySQL table structure?

Tags: mysql, sql

I can't think of a way to improve this MySQL table, I sometimes wonder if it should be like that, if there isn't another way to model it. Currently I have a table of vehicles with ship, boat, train, plane, car, bike, motorcycle and helicopter. Each vehicle has some characteristics that are different between the vehicles.

So we have the **vehicle table** with these columns:

- id
- name
- user_id
- created_at
- **ship**_total_length
- ship_mouth
- ship_point
- ship_ford_freeboard
- ship_freeboard_of_ballast
- **plane**_wing
- plane_landing_gear
- plane_rudder
- plane_propeller
- plane_fuselage
- **bike**_chain
- bike_type_of_pedal
- bike_rim
- bike_gears
- bike_frame

In summary, a user can have several records in the vehicle table and he selects which vehicles will be displayed.

Note that I have placed a vehicle tag before each field. Whenever I add a new vehicle, I have to edit this table and add its columns using a **vehicle_nameOfCharacteristic** tag. This is definitely not the best way to do this, what do you recommend?

Comment: Are these tables even connected in **any** way?

Comment: There are no tables, but only a table called vehicle with these fields I mentioned. I edited it for you to have an idea @NicoHaase

Comment: You should consider modifying your design to better conform to [third normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form). Instead of including attributes only related to a subset of the records in a table, create a table for each unique entity type. If you need a centralized record of these for whatever reason, use a bridge table to track their IDs and other metadata and JOIN them in your queries.

Comment: @esqew I already have this model working, do you think it's worth reworking now that it's in the beginning and has few records or should I keep this design?

Comment: @viniciussvl That's really not something I can answer for you. You'll have to weigh the cost of the effort (time, technology, etc.) vs. the benefits of going to 3NF (standardization, scalability, likely performance improvements). I can say from my own experience in similar scenarios, the benefits have almost always outweighed the costs

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. It's better to do this redesign now before it's too late, I refuse to leave the table design that way knowing it's not the best, if I can change it I'll do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one table? It seems like you should have a new table for each different vehicle type. Each vehicle is it's own object after all, if you're into that sort of thing. Split it into ship, boat, train, plane, car, bike, motorcycle and helicopter tables.  You may also want to use enumeration when referencing between an object and its part. Have a helicopter table and a helicoper_parts table, if you think you'll need it. Database design is pretty complicated and there are a lot of different philosophies so it really comes down to what you're trying to do. If you have 10,000 types of part for each vehicle then it makes sense to have a parts table, and a vehicle specific table, and a larger vehicles table. Just be consistent with whatever you do.

Comment: Yes, this is my table currently. I'll have to modify the design based on the ideas you've given me, to make it better organized.

Comment: I already have this model working, do you think it's worth doing the reformulation and splitting the table for each vehicle?

Comment: 5k @clark-fischer

Comment: ugh that's tough. If you feel like you can break it up easily with some sql commands then it's worth it

Comment: I can write a script to do this split, it's better to do it now before I have 100k records right?

Comment: @basha04 Thanks for the tip, I'll write this script right now. Just a question, is what I'm going to do common? Do people often make design mistakes and need to split tables?